# Android: speeding up shared element transition between activities

Tags: java, android, user-interface, transition

I have a shared element transition between two activities that works in the following way:

```
Intent someintent = new Intent(this, someclass.class);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this
                    , new Pair<>(viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.someimage), "someimage")
                    , new Pair<>(viewClicked.findViewById(R.id.someicon), "someicon")
            );
            startActivity(someintent, options.toBundle());
        }
        else {
            startActivity(someintent);
        }
```

this works fine, but the transition is agonisingly slow. When the image is first clicked on it seems to stall for a second or two before the transition takes place. Is this due to the "weight" of the activity being loaded or is the delay configurable?

Comment: What view are you transitioning to?  I have seen delays when I am using an image that needs to be grabbed from the web - and in this case, I delay the enter transition (part of the API) until the image has been fully downloaded/displayed.

Comment: @Booger I'm transitioning from an activity that holds a recyclerview of images to another activity containing a fragment that has the same image inside it. The view itself is a regular ImageView.

Comment: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/03/activity-postponed-shared-element-transitions-part3b.html.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Did you try change duration of `enterTransition` and `returntransition`:

```
    private Transition enterTransition() {
        ChangeBounds bounds = new ChangeBounds();
        bounds.setDuration(2000);

        return bounds;
    }

    private Transition returnTransition() {
        ChangeBounds bounds = new ChangeBounds();
        bounds.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        bounds.setDuration(2000);

        return bounds;
    }
```

And in `onCreate`:

```
getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(enterTransition());
getWindow().setSharedElementReturnTransition(returnTransition());
```

Answer (score 17):

Another way that may help some that already have the Transitions setup in their styles:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition().setDuration(2000);
    getWindow().getSharedElementReturnTransition().setDuration(2000)
        .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
}
```